# How to Autowire Interface with Implementation

Tags: java, spring, maven, autowired, spring-annotations

I have been Googling the answer for a long time, but I am certain I am missing something that would bring this all together. I am just not sure what. It is failing on running the Spring server with error:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.test.abc.sv.dao.TestDAO com.test.abc.sv.controller.TestController.testDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.abc.sv.dao.TestDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at com.test.abc.sv.SpringLaunch.main(SpringLaunch.java:26)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.test.abc.sv.dao.TestDAO com.test.abc.sv.controller.TestController.testDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.abc.sv.dao.TestDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:290)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.abc.sv.dao.TestDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481)
    ... 18 common frames omitted

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'testController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.test.abc.sv.dao.TestDAO com.test.abc.sv.controller.TestController.testDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.abc.sv.dao.TestDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at com.test.abc.sv.SpringLaunch.main(SpringLaunch.java:26)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.test.abc.sv.dao.TestDAO com.test.abc.sv.controller.TestController.testDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.abc.sv.dao.TestDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:290)
    ... 16 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.test.abc.sv.dao.TestDAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:967)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481)
    ... 18 more
```

So I am running the application from
`SpringLaunch.class - com.test.abc.sv`

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SpringLaunch extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(applicationClass);
}

private static Class<SpringLaunch> applicationClass = SpringLaunch.class;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION ="
                                            +"(LOAD_BALANCE=on)"
                                            +"(FAILOVER=on)"
                                            +"(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=56.276.152.217)(PORT=1521))"
                                            +"(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=56.276.152.218)(PORT=1521))"
                                            +"(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=test.abc.com)))");
        dataSource.setUsername("DevUser");
        dataSource.setPassword("Credential");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public TestDAO testDAO() {
        return new TestDAOImpl(dataSource());
    }
```

}

`TestController.class - com.test.abc.sv.controller`

```
    @RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController{


    @Autowired
    TestDAO testDao;

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/setup", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Message setupTest(@RequestParam(value="id", required=true) String testNumber) {
        String testMsg = new String(); 

        try{
            testMsg = testDao.prepDatabase(testNumber);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            //Log e.getMessage();
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return new Message("-1");
        }

        return new Message(testMsg);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/teardown", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Message teardownTest(@RequestParam(value="id", required=true) String testNumber) {
        String testMsg = new String(); 

        try{
            testMsg = testDao.removeTestData(testNumber);
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            //Log e.getMessage();
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return new Message("-1");
        }

        return new Message(testMsg);
    }

}
```

`TestDAO.class - com.test.abc.sv.dao` Interface

```
 public interface TestDAO {

    public String prepDatabase(String testNumber)
            throws SQLException;

    public String removeTestData(String testNumber)
            throws SQLException;

}
```

`TestDAOImpl.class - com.test.abc.sv.dao'

```
    @Component
public class TestDAOImpl implements TestDAO{

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TestDAOImpl.class);

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public TestDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public String prepDatabase(String testNumber)
            throws SQLException {

        //Impl Stuff

    }

    @Override
    public String removeTestData(String testNumber)
            throws SQLException {

        //Impl Stuff
    } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ComponentScan.html) of `@ComponentScan`:

> If specific packages are not defined scanning will occur from the package of the class with this annotation.

Your `Application` class is in `com.test.abc.sv.controller` package according to your question. So everything in `com.test.abc.sv.controller` and its subppackages will be scanned, but that doesn't include your custom configuration or services because they are not in supbackages of `com.test.abc.sv.controller`.

So the solution would be to move the `Application` class to for example `com.test.abc` package or explicitly define the package to scan as `com.test.abc` for instance.

Also I'm not really sure why are you using that custom configuration class. You can configure data source using [Spring Boot properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties).

And as for the DAO/service bean declarations in your configuration class, that's what the `@Service` or `@Repository` annotation for service and dao respectively are for. So I would suggest getting rid of those too. If you don't you will most likely get another exception, because your beans will be registered once by the component scan and second time from your configuration class, which will result in [NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException.html).

Comment: I am still getting "Error creating bean with name `'testController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.accenture.test.abc.dao.TestDAO com.accenture.usps.sv.controller.TestController.testDao;`

Comment: I combined the Application and Configuration class into a single class and moved it to com.test.abc, but I am still getting the above error. If I manually reference the bean using `ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfiguration.class);
     TestDAO testDao = (TestDAO) context.getBean("testBean");` I can get it to work. If I use Autowired on TestDAO, it dose not work.

Comment: Could you please update the question with current code of your Application class and your DAO class? And also if you combined the Application class with the config class what is the SpringConfiguration class you mention in your last comment?

Comment: I updated the question with and replaced the code. I took out the `TestService` and just routed `TestController` to use `TestDAO` directly for now. It does work when I do not use autowire and just get the `testDao` from the `ApplicationContext` as stated in above comment, but will bomb out on Spring launch if I replace it with Autowire.

Comment: One thing which seems odd to me is that you're defining the DAO bean twice, once using the component annotation and once in your Application class. But I would expect `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` in that case. Can you try removing your DAO bean definition from your Application class to see if that helps? And then also use @Autowired on your DAO constructor to inject the data source using constructor injection.

Comment: I tried removing the DAO bean definition in application, but I got the same problem.